# Shortest Query Possible, Big query for recursive checks

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Let's say I have a data in Big query, as big as of millions of rows for one month. 
For example:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      date           |     user         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          01-12-2019 |   xyz            |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          02-12-2019 |   xyz            |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          03-12-2019 |   abc            |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Now I want to retrieve day wise data, count of repetitive user for next 14 days i.e, user who came on 01-12-2019 for the first time, then the count of repeating users who did visited again in next 14 days (02-12-2019 - 15-12-2019). I figured out the way to retrieve same, but for some specific date, using below Query.

```
 SELECT '2019-12-01' AS visit_date, COUNT(DISTINCT user) AS visitors_count
 FROM `user_data`
 WHERE
 date = '2019-12-01' AND user IN (SELECT user FROM `user_data`
 WHERE date between DATE_ADD('2019-12-01', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND DATE_ADD('2019-12-01', INTERVAL 
 14 DAY) )
 GROUP BY 1
```

One approach, I can use is, UNION ALL, which is probably not a best solution for sure, that's why am willing to know some best practices, I must make habit of, for such situation.

Answer (score 1):

An inline query should be quite efficient here:

```
select 
    date,
    (
        select count(distinct u1.user) 
        from user_data u1 
        where u1.date 
            between date_add(u.date, interval 1 day) 
            and date_add(u.date, interval 14 day)
    ) visitors_count
from (select distinct date from user_data) u
```

For performance, you want an index on `(date, user)`.

If you had a reference table that holds the list of dates available in the table, you could use if instead of doing a `select distinct`: that could speed up the query too.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am getting this error. LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.

Comment: @AmrishMishra: but there is no `left outer join` in this query... Which query are you running that generates this error?

Comment: I simply copied your query.

Comment: As of now, what I figured out is, the alias 'u' isn't accessible to sub query.

Comment: @GMB . . . There is, you just don't see it.  An correlated subquery is really a type of outer join.  The inequality problem  is a common issue in BQ.  This is also not the most efficient approach in any database, if there are lots of dates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thanks for taking the time to comment. Yes I can understand that the query planner turns the inline query to a left join (that's what it essentially is). I was not aware of this equality restriction in Big Query though.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using `union all` and aggregation.  The key is keeping the dates going in *and out*.  So:

```
with ud as (
      select user, date, 1 as inc
      from user_data
      union all
      select user, date_add(date, interval 15 day), -1 as inc
      from user_data
     )
select date,
       sum(inc) as change_on_day,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by date) as total_on_day
from ud
group by date
order by date;
```

EDIT:

You can modify the above to get the *first* positive inc for a customer and the *last*:

```
with ud as (
      select user, date, 1 as inc
      from (select ud.*,
                   lag(date) over (partition by user order by date) as prev_date
            from user_data ud
           ) ud
      where prev_date is null or prev_date < date_add(date, interval -14 day)
      union all
      select user, date_add(date, interval 15 day), -1 as inc
      from (select ud.*,
                   lead(date) over (partition by user order by date) as lead_date
            from user_data ud
           ) ud
      where next_date is null or next_date < date_add(date, interval 14 day)
     )
select date,
       sum(inc) as change_on_day,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by date) as total_on_day
from ud
group by date
order by date;
```

Comment: Wrong output, probably it includes those users which is repeated on that same day too. lastly will you please explain the logic behind if possible. Thank you.

Comment: @AmrishMishra . . . (1) I do explain the logic.  (2) This answers the question that you have asked.  If you have to deal with customers who come back during the "active" period, then ask a new question and be quite explicit about the logic you need.

Comment: I am sorry if their is something rude? I have already mentioned in my question that I need user count which was repeating in next 14 days. please refer the description, below sample table in my question. It would be pleasure to have a discussion over it.

Comment: @AmrishMishra . . . Not rude, just incomplete.  The sample data and the question do not mention "overlaps" in periods of activity.

Comment: @AmrishMishra . . . You question does have `count(distinct)` in your sample query, so I modified the answer to handle overlapping stretches of activity for a single customer.

Answer (score 1):

below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT visit_day, COUNT(DISTINCT IF(visits_next_14_days, NULL, user)) AS repeating_visitors_count 
FROM (
  SELECT visit_day, user, 0 = COUNT(1) OVER(
    PARTITION BY user 
    ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(visit_day) 
    RANGE BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 14 FOLLOWING
  ) visits_next_14_days
  FROM `project.dataset.user_data`
)
GROUP BY visit_day
```

Comment: any resource suggestions to improve my SQL skills?

Comment: Do i have been rude at some point? I am sorry, If I have been at some point, I didn't ment to be intentionality. In case if you have some good resource to share with me, will be lot much help. Thank You once again